# Is it possible remove bounty from a question?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I had added bounty for a question accidentally (*[Getting Git to work with a proxy server - fails with "Request timed out"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server)*). Do I have a way to redo it?

Comment: From [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/398364): "_Can I cancel my bounty?_... _If you feel there are exceptional circumstances, flag the question for moderator attention to explain the situation._"

Comment: It takes quite a number of mouse clicks to add a bounty, how did you do all of them "accidentally" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is not way you can remove/revoke the bounty once you offer it.

For more information, you can check **[here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21529/ability-to-remove-the-bounty-and-get-reputation-back)**